# Override of -navigationBar:shouldPopItem: returned YES after manually popping a view controller

Tags: controller, navigationbar

Basically on the iPhone XR the navigationbar on viewcontroller dismissal terminates due to error :

Override of -navigationBar:shouldPopItem: returned YES after manually popping a view controller (navigationController=)'

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

The exception message already tells you what's going on.
I assume you are manually popping the view controller as stated in the exception message. If you are doing that you just have to return false in your overridden shouldPopItem method. That's it!

Long story short (Code snippet for Xamarin.iOS):

`[Export("navigationBar:shouldPopItem:")]
    public bool ShouldPopItem(UINavigationBar navigationBar, UINavigationItem navigationItem)
    {
        PopViewController(animated: true);
        return false;
    }`